# python 2.7 Integer variable changes in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, int

I run through a matrix of 300 pixels (using Pillow) with a for loop for x and y. At the end I set the variable: lastPixelAvg=PixelAvg, so I can compare it with a new value.

When the next iteration starts, the value has unexpectedly changed. I have tried all kinds of things, like copy.deepcopy() as this may have something to do with the way integers between -5 and 255 are handled. Assigning the variable at the start rather than at the end doesn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

```
brightnessShift=False
deviation=3
lastPixelAvg=0
for x in xrange(100,400,10):
    for y in xrange(200,300,10):
        xy = (x, y)
        rgb = img.getpixel(xy)

        pctR=int(rgb[0]*0.391)      
        pctG=int((rgb[1]-5)*0.391)  
        pctB=int(rgb[2]*0.391)

        pixelAvg=(pctR+pctG+pctB)/3
        if not (x==100):
            print lastPixelAvg # <--- this returns a different value then set at the end, always about 10 higher; for instance 42
            brightnessShift = ((pixelAvg+deviation*2.5)<=lastPixelAvg) or ((pixelAvg-deviation*2.5)>=lastPixelAvg) #!!deviation * 2.5
        else:
            brightnessShift = False

        lastPixelAvg=pixelAvg # here the value is set to, for instance 30, from pixelAvg
        print lastPixelAvg # returns 30
```

Comment: How do you know the values don't match? In the code posted here, you aren't logging the value at the point where `lastPixelAvg` gets set. Can you show us in more detail what makes you think something is changing that shouldn't?

Comment: or step through in pdb to check

Comment: I visualise the output by colouring pixels in the image. I noticed that the second pixel, at (x=110,y=200) almost always had the brigtnessShift state set to true. I tried printing the variables at all kinds of places in the code, it is clear that at the first instruction after the for y command the value has changed. This isn't the full code, but neither values are used after this point (pixelAvg & lastPixelAvg)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pdb tip. I had the for loops the wrong way around.

```
for x in xrange(100,400,10):
    for y in xrange(200,300,10):
```

Should be:

```
for y in xrange(200,300,10):
    for x in xrange(100,400,10):
```

or `if not (y==200):` instead of `if not (x==100):`